# How do join up with a friend in Titan Quest Anniversary Edition?

Tags: steam, titan-quest

I want to play the updated Titan Quest with a friend, in Steam. How can I do that? Using Steam's "join game" or "invite to game" options only send me to the in-game list of multiplayer servers, and that list is completely unusable (can't search, can't scroll, can't sort). What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, looks like it's a known issue being looked at.

Meanwhile, I found [this workaround at the Steam forums](http://steamcommunity.com/app/475150/discussions/0/343785380900791694/):

> Disconnected from wifi.
>   Selected friends game.
>   When the password screen came up, I reconnected and waiting a moment.
>   Put in password, joined game (also alt-tabbed to make sure my firewall wasnt clogging).

Update: [the developers are saying they fixed it](http://steamcommunity.com/app/475150/discussions/0/343785380903937831/).